# System freeze on upload

Tags: windows-7, internet, freeze, upload

when i'm uploading anything to the Internet sometime my Computer freezes and I have to do a hard reset. It doesn't happen all the time, just sometimes (on big uploads like dropbox).

There is no event for the error in the system protocol("Ereignisanzeige" on german).

I'm not really sure what Infos i need to include, for you to help me...

This is my PC-Configuration

http://speccy.piriform.com/results/yt0QpJepQ6DWTcn6aKeexfy

Answer (score 0):

Check your internet speed, if its slow connection, the system hangs up while uploading data. If this is not the case, than try re installing the dropbox software or any other you use. It will sort it out.

Comment: It happens also on Firefox, Chrome. It only happens on big uploads, i test the speed later, but i think it always has a quite good speed.

Comment: it also happens on network transactions

Answer (score 0):

A complete freeze usually means an Operating system or most likely hardware problem, nothing to do with your browser. Does you computer ever freeze when you're not uploading . If it's mostly when you messing with big uploads it might be a hard drive problem (that portion of hard drive corrupted). 
Try copying the thing that you want to upload to another folder of your hard drive and upload from that location.

Run Super Pi for an hour or so. If your computer freezes or the test fails you know theirs a problem. To complete factor out the cpu + memory, you'll want to run Super PI overnight. 
Stability/Torture test
Super PI - tests cpu + memory in Windows [link](http://files.extremeoverclocking.com/file.php?f=36)

Regards,

Comment: No it doesn't freeze when theres no upload traffic. It happens only on long uploads, i never had it while normal browsing. It also happens on distributing files and folders over the local network. I don't think it's a hard drive issue because big copies and stuff ... don't freeze the computer. I will try your suggestions but I don't think it has to do with hard drive/memory. Thanks for your Help though :)